# Connect to MySQL (WAMP) via SSH

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

Hi I installed the latest WAMP on Windows 7. I would like connect via SSH to MySQL database and create dump.

As SSH client I use PUTTY.

I tried using the root account and also other accounts, but I get this error:

> server unexpectedly closed network connection

Then I tried using another SSH client Private Shell http://www.privateshell.com/

I get this error:

> other side does not support SSH protocol on this port

For connection I use these settings:

- IP: localhost
- PORT: 3306

MySQL version is 5.5.16 I am not sure if support SSH connection.

Is it needed to allow SSH in phpAdmin or what is the root of problem?

Comment: No, MySQL doesn't support SSH in any way. You probably want SSL secured connection?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a SSH server on your machine?? If not you may install [copssh - OpenSSH for Windows](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) or similar and then try to connect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ssh server running on windows. I use [bitvise winsshd](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd)

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- [Configure SSL on the server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-connections.html)
- Connect using the [MySQL command line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html), *not* PuTTY which is a terminal emulator

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\MYSQL_VERSION\bin`

Hit shift + right-click in that folder and select "Open command window here" from the menu that pops up.

This will open a command window in the path you are already in, so C:\wamp\bin\mysql\MYSQL_VERSION\bin

Enter any of the MySQL commands you like with any of the executables you find in that folder.

For example check this post to learn how to use mysqldump.exe to back up or restore any of your MySQL databases: https://css-tricks.com/back-wordpress-database/

For WAMP on Windows and a local development environment you or rather your PC is the MYSQL Server.

Have fun.

edit:
Regarding the downvote I would be curious to hear why on Windows with a local WAMP installation this is not perceived a good method. It works flawless every time. Happy to learn more about this, a constructive comment or edit of my answer would be great in this case. Thank you. :)

Comment: The downvote is because the question is about an SSH issue, which your answer says nothing about.

Comment: @ypercube yes, totally right, I get it, thank you for the heads up. I figured most posts on this mention SSH as the examples are either for Unix system or for live servers, so SSH is a must there. For local work this should suffice, but yes, you are right, the question is tagged SSH. Thank you. ;)

Comment: yes, I meant that if you said something like "no, this can't be done with ssh in Windows or you need to install this and here is an alternative" the answer would be ok. And for the record, this is a very old question and not a very good or clear one. I voted to close it as well.

Comment: @ypercube Yeah probably best to close it, I take your point, though for new users this is an easy way to have a very first and tiny sense of achievement, if this is not closed in some days time I will add more info to my answer to incorporate the SSH part as well. Or hey, if you like to edit my answer and add the SSH bit, that would help all of the readers of this. As you like. Thank you.

Comment: Let me get my bits and bobs about SSH on Windows right and I will surly edit this, fingers crossed. Would not want to add info that is not correct.

Comment: @ypercube what suggests I am considering the downvote personal? My repeated offer for constructive help or inviting others, including yourself, to edit the reply? I like to suggest my emotional intelligence is high enough to separate the content of a reply on stack from my persona and capabilities as such, but thanks for caring, I seen other people take this bad for sure. No offence taken. SSH info incoming..

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to imply that. Your response is great and sorry. I've just seen too many users caring too much for downvotes and you seem to know what you are saying (noticed the other answer, too). When you have enough rep, you can join us at [the Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-) by the way.

Comment: This SSH on Windows, or rather with WAMPserver turns out to be quite a journey and then OP wont have Unix commands e.g. CHMOD, so CygWin and OpenSSH or other choices but that busts the scope of the original question really. The thing is this is for local use since all webhosts already have SSH and are Linux/Unix based (well most). I see why OP is asking about SSH, it is because all the tuts and posts talk about this, not taking into consideration Win users, so OP thinks he needs SSH while only wanting to make a dump. Get this closed if you can please. Thx 4 heaps up on Th Heap. All cool Laters

Answer (score -1):

Much simpler way to go about this.

Copy cmd.exe from your system32 folder, copy to: C:\wamp\bin\mysql\MYSQL_VERSION\bin

Open cmd, run the following command:

```
mysqldump.exe -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DB_NAME > "DIRECTORY_TO_DUMP.sql" --lock-tables=false
```

Replace MYSQL_VERSION, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DIRECTORY_TO_DUMP with appropriate values.

Using the various executables, you can do pretty much anything.